# Plotly: How to display different color/line segments on a line chart for specified condition?

Tags: plotly, plotly-dash, linechart, plotly-python

I'm trying to plot a line chart that differentiates the line color and the line itself(i.e. using a dash or dotted lines) based on a specific condition.
The figure isn't showing the lines/change in line color but I could see the change in the color of data points on the plot when I hovered over the chart and also in the legend.

```
fig = px.line(df2, x=df2['Time_Stamp'], y=df2['Blob_1_Prob_48H'])
count = 0
for j, y in enumerate(df2.Blob_1_Prob_48H):
    if count==0:
        count +=1
        fig.add_traces(go.Scatter(
        x = [df2['Time_Stamp'][j]],
        y = [df2['Blob_1_Prob_48H'][j]],
        mode = "lines+markers",
        name = "48H",                    
        text= df2.Name,
        hovertemplate="Prediction Percentage: %{y}<br>Date &Time: %{x}<br>Name: %{text}<extra></extra>"))
    else:
        if df2['Blob_1_Prob_48H'][j] < df2['Blob_1_Prob_48H'][j-1]:
            fig.add_traces(go.Scatter(
                x = [df2['Time_Stamp'][j]],
                y = [df2['Blob_1_Prob_48H'][j]],
                mode = 'lines',
                name = "48H",    
                line = dict(color='red',width=5, dash='dot'),                
                text= df2.Name,
                hovertemplate="Prediction Percentage: %{y}<br>Date &Time: %{x}<br>Name: %{text}<extra></extra>"))
        
fig.update_layout(title="ALEX(S)",xaxis_title='Date & time',yaxis_title='Blob percentage',yaxis_range=[0,105],showlegend=True,width=1200,
                  height=600)
fig.show()
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1oJCo.png)

Comment: Not sure if I understand what you want: do you want to create a single line plot but the lines between some of the points are dashed and others are dotted? In your code, you are creating one line plot with `px.line` (in blue) and then one scatter plot for each element in the loop.

Comment: I wanted to create a single line chart with different color patterns and different line representations when a certain criterion is met. 
@Filipe Please let me know how this can be achieved.

Comment: I think you cannot do that on the same curve. You'd have to first separate the points into the curves you need different properties, then add all the different curves to the traces.

Comment: @Filipe
I think now I'm getting ur point. if possible could you help me with a sample code or any sort of example elaborating this scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are certainly better ways to do this, but here is one code where I separate a list into many increasing and decreasing curves and then plot them with different styles:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import random

xs = [i for i in range(100)]
ys = [random.randint(1,30) for i in range(100)]

# Temporary lists to store each consecutive increasing or decreasing values
x_inc = []
y_inc = []
x_dec = []
y_dec = []
# List to gather all increasing and decreasing curves
xs_inc = []
ys_inc = []
xs_dec = []
ys_dec = []
# Indicate if it is the first point of new list
first_inc = True
first_dec = True
# Looping over original values
for i in range(len(ys)-1):
    if ys[i+1] < ys[i]:
        if first_inc: # If it is the first, add initial point...
            x_dec.append(xs[i])
            y_dec.append(ys[i])
            if y_inc: # ... and add other to list, if not empty
                xs_inc.append(x_inc)
                ys_inc.append(y_inc)
        x_dec.append(xs[i+1])
        y_dec.append(ys[i+1])
        first_inc = False

        # Restarting all
        x_inc = []
        y_inc = []
        first_dec = True
    else:
        if first_dec: # If it is the first, add initial point...
            x_inc.append(xs[i])
            y_inc.append(ys[i])
            if y_dec: # ... and add other to list, if not empty
                xs_dec.append(x_dec)
                ys_dec.append(y_dec)
        x_inc.append(xs[i+1])
        y_inc.append(ys[i+1])
        first_dec = False

        # Restarting all
        x_dec = []
        y_dec = []
        first_inc = True

fig = go.Figure()

# Plotting all increasing curves
for i, (x, y) in enumerate(zip(xs_inc,ys_inc)):
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=x,
                            y=y, 
                            name = 'Increase',
                            legendgroup = 'increase', # Group them together
                            showlegend=(True if i == 0 else False), # Only add legend to the first
                            line = dict(color='blue',width=3, dash='dash'),
                            mode="lines",
                            ))
# Plotting all decreasing curves
for i, (x, y) in enumerate(zip(xs_dec,ys_dec)):
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=x,
                            y=y, 
                            name = 'Decrease',
                            legendgroup = 'decrease', # Group them together
                            showlegend=(True if i == 0 else False), # Only add legend to the first
                            line = dict(color='red',width=3, dash='dot'),
                            mode="lines",
                            ))

fig.show()
```

Output:
[image: decreasing and increasing curves]

If you have large amount of numbers, you should adapt to numpy or pandas, for example.